# Непроизносимые согласные

Tags: орфография

Как определить, есть в слове непроизносимая согласная или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прежде всего, стоит попробовать изменить слово так, чтобы, если непроизносимая согласная в слове есть, она стала слышна.
Пример: *сер**д**це — сер**д**ец, страс**т**ный — страс**т**и, опасность — опасаться*
Но есть и исключения. Например, "лес**т**ница", хоть проверочное слово "лесенка".
С непроизносимыми согласными пишутся такие непроверяемые слова, как "чу**в**ство" и "сверс**т**ник".
Также, вопреки проверочным словам без непроизносимой согласной пишутся: "блеснуть" (хотя блестеть), серчать (хотя сердиться).
Непроверяемыми являются: шествовать, яства, ровесник.
Слово "косность" пишется без непроизносимой согласной в знечении "неспособность принимать что-то новое", но с непроизносимой согласной Т - в значении "состоящий из костей" (кос**т**ность)